# Bootstrap Based Page Has Lots of Empty White Space at Bottom & Footer Isn't Displaying Correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the page in question: http://sdgsdgsdgsdg.atwebpages.com/

I based this off the official static navbar example: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/

And the official sticky footer example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

I have a facebook page plugin on the page as well as a bootstrap carousel. I removed all code for both of these to see if the problems would disappear but they havent.

My problem is that at the bottom of the page there is a lot of white space, nearly filling up half the page.

The second problem is the sticky footer isnt displaying correctly. Its not showing the silver color and size of the official example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/navbar-static-top.css, which includes the following:

```
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}
```

Therefore, your page is 2,000 pixels high, creating your big white blank area at the bottom. (Just like in the example, incidentally.)

As for the footer, the example you link to references view-source:http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/sticky-footer.css, which includes this bit:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Since you haven't included those rules, they don't apply on your site.

You really need to get acquainted with your browser's inspector, particularly the parts revolving around CSS inspection. This approach of including random pieces of code without understanding *what they do* won't work long-term.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes I will definitely read up on what you said. For some reason, adding the css you mentioned to my custom css fixed the white space. The footer is also working but its stuck in about the middle of the page.

Comment: Again, you're using stuff without understanding it. The `position: absolute` you've copied/pasted now overrides the `position: fixed` of the *fixed header*. You need to start a basic CSS tutorial - it's not really possible to customize Bootstrap without that knowledge.